# What is the probability of passing using the coin method?

Tags: probability-distributions

**The problem reads as follows:**

A multiple choice exam has 20 questions, 4 posible answers for each.
A student decides to flip a coin on every question and choose the answer like this:

Choice - Toss

1-HEADS, HEADS

2-HEADS, TAILS

3-TAILS, HEADS

4-TAILS, TAILS

A 60% of correct answers is needed in order to pass.
What is the probability of passing using the coin method?

---

It seems like the problem is captious. I think of the number 12 (60% of 20) as the value of the random variable in a binomial distribution, since the probability of choosing the right answer is 0.25 in every coin toss. Now I can apply the formula:

$$ P(X=x) = f(x; n, p) = \binom{n}{x}p^x(1 - p)^{n-x} $$

where p = 0.25, n = 20 and x = 12; such as:

$$P(X=12) = f(12; 20, 0.25) \\ P(X=12) = \binom{20}{12}(0.25)^{12}(0.75)^8 $$

Now, that gives me the probability of the student answering correctly EXACTLY 12 questions. I must add the, also favorable, cases where P(20 >= X > 12)

**Am I missing something here?**

Thanks for your time.

PD: Feel free to correct my grammar/notation if needed, it'll be appreciated.

Comment: You need to include $X=20$, so in total you want $P(12\le X\le 20) = 1 - P(X \le 11)$

Comment: Thanks, @AlexR btw: how do you use math notation inline?

Comment: Enclose it in single dollar signs. Note that you can right click on any formula and display the TeX that produced it.

Comment: @paranoidhominid As Brian said: `$a^2+b^2=c^2$` produces $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Comment: Regarding the title, who says something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea; you need the sum of all favourable outcomes, which is 12 or more correct questions: take the odds of exactly 12 questions, exactly 13 questions, and so forth. This give us the probability as
$$\sum_{k=12}^{20}\binom{20}k\left(\frac14\right)^k\left(\frac34\right)^{20-k} = 0.0935\%$$
which is unfortunately very bad odds for the student :( Study up!